# Searching a DataTable for a DataType

Tags: c#, .net, linq, datetime, datatable

Struggling to find any relevant info. online for this one. Admittedly I'm not well versed in linq expressions, which is likely a handicap.

I currently have a list of DataTables and want to search all of them specifically for any DateTime variables present in order to change the values to local timezones.

Not all tables will contain a DateTime and the relevant column will vary.

Ideally I need something like.

```
Foreach table in resultTables
    Foreach row in table.rows
        if row contains dataType(DateTime) then [change value]
```

(Or Something similar but column by column instead)

Up until know I haven't even been able to even access the individual table elements. A little quickwatch shows the value I'm looking for to be in

```
((System.Data.DataRow)((new System.Linq.SystemCore_EnumerableDebugView(table.Rows)).Items[0])).ItemArray[1]
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
    var dateColumns = dt.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>().Where(x => x.DataType == typeof(DateTime));
    foreach (DataColumn column in dateColumns)
    {
        foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
        {
            row[column.ColumnName] = DateTime.Parse("1/1/4");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Quick-and-dirty version, I'd go for something like this:

```
        foreach (DataTable table in resultTables) {
            foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows) {
                foreach (DataColumn col in table.Columns) {
                    if (col.DataType == typeof (DateTime)) {
                        row[col] = // do something
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Of course if you have a lot of rows in a table, you could improve by keeping track of columns found in a temporary list. Or switch the row and column loops around.